# My .map method doesnt work properly in function

Tags: flutter, dart

I dont know why the method .map is totally ignored. Even after deleted conditions, it doesnt add widgets to my list. It seems like groupsToRename.map() doesnt exist at all.

```
List<Widget> listRenamedGroups(
          List<MapEntry<int, String>> groupsToRename) {
        final List<Widget> resultList = [];
        final currentGroups =
            (bloc.state as ListSuccessfullState<GroupViewModel>).viewModels;
        groupsToRename.map((groupRenameEntry) {
          final correspondingOldEntry = currentGroups
              .firstWhere((element) => element.groupId == groupRenameEntry.key);
          if (correspondingOldEntry == null ||
              correspondingOldEntry.name != groupRenameEntry.value) {
            resultList.add(Text(
              '${correspondingOldEntry.name} --> ${groupRenameEntry.value}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: ColorsExtension.textGreyLight),
            ));
          }
        });
        return resultList;
      }
```

Comment: So.. Where is bloc defined? Also, show more code

Comment: Lists from groupsToRename and currentGroups  are 100% works. The only problem is how to deal with this map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `toList()` after `map()`, or replace map with forEach

Answer (score 1):

You should really not be using `.map()` here since you are not assigning the result to anything. A for loop is really what you want in your case.

Now, as to why in your examples, it appeared that `.map()` wasn't doing anything is becasue in dart, `.map()` is `lazy` in a sense that it really returns an iterator. It's not really iterating over the list unless you explicitly consume the list (say, with `.toList()`).